# Incorrect yml syntax in ansible-playbook

Tags: ansible, yaml

Can anyone help me to fix this playbook:

```yaml
---
- name: Deploying httpd container using GIT Repo for web content - part3
  hosts: Docker-hosts
  tasks:
  - name: Correct python version selected
    community.general.alternatives:
        name: python
        path: /usr/bin/python3
  - name: Install bottle python package
    pip:
        name: docker-py
  - name: pulling docker image
    docker_image:
        name: httpd
        source: pull
  - name: creating a container
    docker_container:
         name: webos
         image: httpd
         volumes:
               -   /root/ansible1/index.html:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/
         ports:
               -   "82:80"
         state: started
         detach: yes
```

**I am getting this general syntax error:**

```
ERROR! couldn't resolve module/action 'community.general.alternatives'. This often indicates a misspelling, missing collection, or incorrect module path.
The error appears to be in '/etc/ansible/playbooks/Install_Docker_on_Centos8-p3_updated.yml': line 5, column 5, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.
The offending line appears to be:
  tasks:
  - name: Correct python version selected
    ^ here
```

I guess this is spaces issue but I don't find the problem
thanks

Comment: from your post, I can see spaces issue. You only give two spaces not 4 or 5 spaces to the argument under your module name.

Comment: Though spacing is unconventional, I don't think that's causing this issue. What's the version of Ansible?

Comment: Very probably the collection ``community.general`` is missing. See ``shell> ansible-galaxy collection list``. If the collection is really missing install it ``shell> ansible-galaxy collection install community.general``

Comment: Hi Ofer Wessboim welcome to SO. A question that often bites newcomers to ansible as that the `community.general.alternatives:` module style in the `latest` documentation is, appropriately, only for the latest ansible versions, and since you didn't include the version you are using, we can't say for sure but likely it's 2.9 or older, which means you would need to continue to use the modules that shipped with your installed copy

Comment: My ansible version is 2.9.23. I've tried to list my collection by shell> ansible-galaxy collection list and to install it but just got this error (when trying to install): "ERROR! Unknown error when attempting to call Galaxy at 'https://galaxy.ansible.com/api/': <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>"

Answer (score 0):

please try the YAML below and see if it runs. I have corrected the spaces in the file I thik it should work. If it the issue still persists, please share the Ansible version that you are currently using.

```
- 
  hosts: Docker-hosts
  name: "Deploying httpd container using GIT Repo for web content - part3"
  tasks: 
    - 
      community.general.alternatives: 
        name: python
        path: /usr/bin/python3
      name: "Correct python version selected"
    - 
      name: "Install bottle python package"
      pip: 
        name: docker-py
    - 
      docker_image: 
        name: httpd
        source: pull
      name: "pulling docker image"
    - 
      docker_container: 
        detach: true
        image: httpd
        name: webos
        ports: 
          - "82:80"
        state: started
        volumes: 
          - "/root/ansible1/index.html:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/"
      name: "creating a container"
```

Comment: it doesn't seem like a YAML format. I don't understand why you have missing --- in the begining of the file and the tasks are not begin with - as well